# Struts2 Radio: how to customize the value of the input

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am making a survey web app. For each question, I have like this:

Question: this is a question. Please select the best choice.

1. This is Option 1;
2. This is Option 2;
3. This is Option 3.

*The option list is dynamic.

And I am using Struts2 radio

So in my Java action class, I have

```
question.addOptions("This is option 1.");
question.addOptions("This is option 2.");
question.addOptions("This is option 3.");
```

And in my jsp, I have

```
<s:radio label="Please select the best choice" name="answer" list="options"/>
```

where "answer" is an attribute(instance variable) of my action class, to record the selection.

So right now as I select one of the options, I can see "answer" record the value as "This is Option x". Not bad.

However, **here is what I want to achieve**. I want "answer" to value "x" instead of "This is Option x." But I have really not found a way to customize this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)  Solution using JSP Change

Here value of x is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. Instead of "This is Option x"

```
<s:radio label="YourQuestion" name="yourAnswer" list="#{'1':' This is Option 1','2':' This is Option 2','3':' This is Option 3','4':' This is Option 4'}" value="1" />
```

value attribute will set the default value.
list will contain the radio button values.

2) EDIT: Another Solution Using Java

For Dynamic Options create something like this

```
 public class RadioOptions{

           private String key;
           private String value;
           //getter and setter methods
        }
```

Here you can retrieve the calls using the key value.

```
List<RadioOptions> radioOption= new ArrayList<RadioOptions>();
        radioOption.add( new RadioOptions("1", "This is option 1.") );
        radioOption.add( new RadioOptions("2", "This is option 2.") );
        radioOption.add( new RadioOptions("3", "This is option 3.") );
        radioOption.add( new RadioOptions("4", "This is option 4.") );
```

Your HTML Tag look like this.

```
<s:radio label="Please select the best choice" name="answer" list="radioOption" 
 listKey="key" listValue="value" value="1" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, I am not sure if your answer can apply to my case since my option list is Dynamic. (Forgot to mentioned that in my question)

Comment: Do you have any idea how to deal with a dynamic list?

Comment: Yeah!! listKey is the thing I'm looking for! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I didn't do exactly as you said so I didn't create a new class just for radio options, but made listKey="status.count", works as I want it to.